# XML PARSING ON ORACLE (HELP :/)

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xml-parsing

I have xml data like this;

```
<NctsYYSResponse xmlns="http://http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <Root>
        <Response xmlns="">
           <RefID>11084672</RefID>
           <Guid>b2231713</Guid>
           <Durum>Thank You!</Durum>
        </Response>
     </Root>
  </NctsYYSResponse>
```

I tried this sql codes but i could not get result;

```
      1- SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (XMLType(xml_respond) , '/NctsYYSResponse/Root/Response/Guid') guid from table1 


      2-SELECT x.GUID,x.STATUS FROM table1,XMLTABLE(
'/NctsYYSResponse/Root/Response'
PASSING XMLTYPE(xml_respond) 
COLUMNS
"GUID" VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'Guid',
"STATUS" VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'Durum') x ;


3-select x.GUID  from table1, xmltable(
     xmlnamespaces ('http://http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "a" , 
     default ''), '/NctsYYSResponse/Root/a:Response'
     passing XMLType(xml_respond) 
      columns
       "GUID" VARCHAR2(20) path 'Guid'
   ) x  ;
```

Return null at all of them

If i change NctsYYSResponse 's type xmlns to xmlns:xsi , i can get result. But i need to get result when it is xmlns . Please help me :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close with your last attempt; you just applied the `a` namespace to the wrong elements:

```
select x.guid, x.status
from table1
cross apply xmltable (
  xmlnamespaces (
    'http://http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "a", 
    default ''
  ),
  '/a:NctsYYSResponse/a:Root/Response'
  passing XMLType(xml_respond) 
  columns
    guid VARCHAR2(20) path 'Guid',
    status VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'Durum'
) x;
```

```
GUID                 STATUS
-------------------- ---------------
b2231713             Thank You!
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6942802730b5135591b4b8d4d71f8199)